# Changing MVC DisplayFor to not display Id fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to use the templating functionality in MVC 3 to make it easier to create view/edit screens for a range of objects.

I've started by simply using Html.DisplayForModel() - I would now like to customize the different fields in my Model so that the same type of field would always be displayed in the same way.  That's the idea anyways - I'm still trying to figure out how useful templating really is.

Now if I just use Html.DisplayForModel it just does a div with the name of the field and another div with the value.  So for example a Name property will get rendered as

```
<div class="display-label">Name</div>
<div class="display-field">Bob</div>
```

Ok, I can work with that - but for example an Id field will also be displayed that way.  So I tried to override how the Id field will be displayed according to [this](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/10/overriding-displayfor-and-editorfor-to-create-custom-outputs-for-mvc/) blog.  Problem is, if I do that (I changed the Id field to be a hidden input) it still puts the label div in there.

Is it possible to control both the label and field divs for each property?  Or do I have to do the entire template (instead of just customizing the field)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set ScaffoldColumn attribute on Id property. See more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.scaffoldcolumnattribute.aspx).